# Shiny: build entire UI using index.html

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to build the entire ui.r using index.html with the ref here :http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html . But I cannot get the plot displayed in the page (a div with id="plot" class="shiny-plot-output" in index.html), so I am wondering where could I get the following files:

shared/shiny.js
shared/shiny.css

Comment: *"where could I get the following files: ..."* Did you forget to list the files?

Comment: <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>

Comment: You don't have to get them. Shiny automatically provides them when you `shiny::runApp`.